# error: no viable conversion from 'edge' to 'const value_type'?

Tags: c++, list, oop, vector, graph

I am simply trying to implement a directed weighted graph using vectors, lists, and classes in C++ however I am getting this error. The line it is giving me this error is line 42:21 where `graph[u].push_back(edge(v, w));`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class edge
{
    private:
        int cost;
        int vertex;
    public:
        edge(int vertex, int cost)
        {
            this->vertex = vertex;
            this->cost = cost;
        }
        int getVertex() const
        {
            return vertex;
        }
        int getCost() const
        {
            return cost;
        }
};

class Graph
{
    private:
        int V;  
        std::vector<std::list<edge> > *graph;
    public:
        Graph(int V);
        void addEdge(int u, int v, int w);
        void DFS();
};
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    graph = new std::vector<std::list<edge> >(V);
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w)
{
    graph[u].push_back(edge(v, w));
}
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`graph` is a pointer to a vector, not a vector, so you want:

```
(*graph)[u].push_back(edge(v, w));
```

But it doesn't seem to need to be a pointer. Wouldn't it be simpler as just a plain vector? It would fix your memory leak too.

Comment: If I remove it from being a pointer, it gives me this error: error: no viable overloaded '=' graph = new std::vector<std::list<edge> >(V);

Comment: Delete the `new`. Or, better, use member initialisers in your constructor.